# Eclipse memory analyzer Heap dump analysis

Tags: memory-leaks, jvm, heap-memory, heap-dump

recently I have downloaded some 5/6GB size heap dumps, and with great surprise I've noted with Eclipse Memory Analyzer that the leaks suspects report show me a problem total size of circa 500MB, the same for the dominator tree histogram.

[image]

So why the analyzer is showing just 500MB of the 6GB dump?

Comment: Maybe your heap dump contains dead objects while MAT is configured to only show live objects? Besides that: https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/heapdump-is-a-lie/

Comment: Thank you for your sharing! I tried also to get a live heap dump that force a GC cycle before getting the dump: in this case the hprof file was circa 5GB.

I'm trying to figure out why sometimes some kubernetes pods restart for a memory spike and, in that case I'd assume that a memory leak occur. In past I have discovered in this way memory leaks. From the link you have posted seems that Eclipse MAT behaves well also with JOL, so I can't figure out anything. :S

Comment: The takeaway of the article is that the heap dump format differs significantly from the actual heap memory, so you can’t deduce the heap size from the dump file size and the heap size estimated by the tools can be different from both, the dump file size and the actual heap size. It might still be worth looking at what potential problems MAT has identified.